# What is the reason for '' error file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found'' in ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair, grubrescue

This is the third time when I have to reinstall ubuntu because of this problem. Please tell me what am I doing wrong? [image]

Answer (score 1):

I used to get that error message when I installed Ubuntu to USB drives. My solution was to have a separate partition with Mount Point `/boot`, but I understand from Ask ubuntu that it is rare for computers to need a separate boot partition.

Answer (score 0):

During grub-install needed files are copied from `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/` to `/boot/grub/i386-pc/`
Maybe this works. Can you boot a live-linux? Mount your /-Partition from your system and try to copy the missing file and reboot. When you have access to your System reinstall grub and update grub-configuration.